# How to align the text under and side of the image and put them in same row with css bootstrap 4

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I want to align the 2 different texts side and under the image as 1 article.
and want to put 2 articles in same row when the window size is col-md or bigger.

[image]
I want the second article to be displayed under the article 1 when the window size is smaller than col-sm.

[image]

I have tried the below code but I could not put them in same row.
How to put them in the same row?

```
  <div class="row">
      <div class = 'col-4 col-md-2'>
        <img class="rounded-circle" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" width="150" alt="Generic placeholder image">
      </div>

      <div class="col-8 col-md-4">
        <p>"aricle 1 : Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec varius venenatis neque, id commodo magna fermentum id."
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
        <p>"article 2 : Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec varius venenatis neque, id commodo magna fermentum id."
      </div>
  </div>


  <div class="row">
      <div class = 'col-4 col-md-2'>
        <img class="rounded-circle" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" width="150" alt="Generic placeholder image">
      </div>

      <div class="col-8 col-md-4">
        <p>"aricle 1 : Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec varius venenatis neque, id commodo magna fermentum id."
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
        <p>"aricle 2: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec varius venenatis neque, id commodo magna fermentum id."
      </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use display:flex; for the row.For when screen size is less, you should consider @media queries.If you need anything else, please let me know.

```css
@media all and (min-width:992px){
  .art{
      margin-left:80px;
  }
  }
@media all and (min-width:768px) and (max-width:991px){
  .art{
      margin-left:100px!important;
  }
}
@media all and (min-width:768px){
  .container{
      display:flex;
      flex-direction:row;
  }
  .row{
      flex-direction:row;
      
  }
}

.row{
     display:flex;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
      <div class ="col-4 col-md-2">
        <img class="rounded-circle" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" width="150" alt="Generic placeholder image">
      </div>

      <div class="art col-8 col-md-6">
        <p>"article 1 : Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec varius venenatis neque, id commodo magna fermentum id."
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
        <p>"article 2 : Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec varius venenatis neque, id commodo magna fermentum id."
      </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
      <div class ="col-4 col-md-2">
        <img class="rounded-circle" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" width="150" alt="Generic placeholder image">
      </div>

      <div class="art col-8 col-md-6">
        <p>"article 1 : Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec varius venenatis neque, id commodo magna fermentum id."
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
        <p>"article 2: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec varius venenatis neque, id commodo magna fermentum id."
      </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Most Welcome :).

Comment: Hi sorry, your code is working perfectly when the window size is below sm, but the article 1(text A) is displaying under the image but not next to the image when the window size is md or bigger. Is there any way to fix this??

and width of the text area becomes very narrow when window size is md..